# accept error for udp select

Tags: sockets, udp

I am trying a simple program to use `select()` with UDP, but when I send data to the UDP port, the program exits with an error "Operation not supported" when calling `accept()`.

My code is from [Handle multiple socket connections with fd_set and select on Linux](https://www.binarytides.com/multiple-socket-connections-fdset-select-linux/), with the change being that I am creating the socket with `SOCK_DGRAM` instead of `SOCK_STREAM`:

```
if( (master_socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0)) == 0)
```

The referred code works just fine.

To send a UDP packet, I am using the command:

```
echo "this is my udp data">>/dev/udp/127.0.0.1/8888
```

Comment: The "udt" tag you have used says you should not use the "udt" tag. Do you mean UDP ? Please also explain what "udt::select" means, is it some library we should know about ? Other than that, your post does not contain any information that can be used to help you. Post your code, it might contain bugs that the code in your link does not have. Also post how you test your code, you could be doing something wrong when testing.

Comment: Thanks fr your comment. I have corrected my question.

Comment: UDP is not connection oriented - accept() only works on connection oriented protocols, so you can not use it with UDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`accept()` only works with connection-orieted protocols, like TCP (`SOCK_STREAM`).  It does not work for connection-less protocols, like UDP (`SOCK_DGRAM`).  This is clearly stated in the [`accept()` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html):

> The accept() system call is used with connection-based socket types (SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_SEQPACKET)...
>
> ...
>
> Errors
>   ...
>   EOPNOTSUPP
>   The referenced socket is not of type SOCK_STREAM.

In UDP, all you need is to `bind()` the socket, and then you can use `recvfrom()` to read inbound packets, and `sendto()` to send outbound packets.